# Docker Compose - Cant connect to MySQL from separate Nginx container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

I'm struggling with the following docker setup.. everything runs on its own fine but for some reason my nginx container can't connect to the mysql one, I've followed countless tutorials on this and none of them work for me so any advice would be excellent.. my docker compose is as follows (fpm and nginx work perfectly)..

```
# web server
nginx:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443" 
  volumes:
    # app
    - ./app/src:/usr/share/nginx/html
    # nginx configs
    - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
    - ./nginx/snippets/:/etc/nginx/snippets/:ro    
    # certificates
    - ./nginx/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem:ro
    - ./nginx/letsencrypt/privkey.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem:ro
    # logs    
    # - ./logs/nginx-error.log:/var/log/nginx/error.log
    # - ./logs/nginx-access.log:/var/log/nginx/access.log    
  links:
    - fpm:__DOCKER_PHP_FPM__
    - db
# php-fpm
fpm:
  build: ./php-fpm
  ports:
    - "9000"
  volumes:
    - ./app/src:/usr/share/nginx/html
    - ./php-fpm/php-production.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "admin"
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
```

when I run docker-compose up mysql splurts out a couple of interesting lines

```
    db_1     | 2017-08-01T17:53:15.872664Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
    db_1     | 2017-08-01T17:53:15.872716Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
    db_1     | 2017-08-01T17:53:15.872723Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
    db_1     | 2017-08-01T17:53:15.872736Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
    db_1     | 2017-08-01T17:53:15.911242Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
    db_1     | Version: '5.7.19'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

looks like it's not accepting TCP connections and using the socket address in my wp-config.php database file doesn't work either.

This is basically what is coming up on the wordpress install screen:

```
 Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /usr/share/nginx/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538
```

Interestingly I can connect to the database no problem from either SequelPro or MySQL workbench.. Im very new to docker (and docker compose) so maybe I'm missing something or a step here?

I'm running docker on osx if that matters.

docker ps outputs:

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
    060ac535e91e        nginx:latest           "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   dockerlnmpmaster_nginx_1
    56db5e7bf9c1        mysql                  "docker-entrypoint..."   10 minutes ago      Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                     dockerlnmpmaster_db_1
    6b8d6e4bec5f        dockerlnmpmaster_fpm   "php-fpm"                10 minutes ago      Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:32813->9000/tcp                    dockerlnmpmaster_fpm_1
```

Comment: How did you connect from SequelPro or Workbench and what IP address are you using in `/usr/share/nginx/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php `??

Comment: its weird.. Im just connecting to 127.0.0.1 and port 3306.. but when I use those details in the wordpress install it doesnt work..

Comment: also when i bash into the nginx container and install curl it cant reach 127.0.0.1:3306 either

Comment: If I understand correctly ... In wordpress you cannot use localhost IP address. Docker uses alias for this so in wordpress you should use 'db' which is service name instead of `127.0.0.1` just use `db:3306` in wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

The issue most probably is that when you are testing your MySQL access on your host machine and not inside a docker container. So if you connect using localhost:3306. It works. That is because for you `db` service the ports are mapped `3306:3306`.

But this service is not localhost inside your compose containers. It is referred by the service name. Which is `db` in your case. So when you configure you wordpress, you need to make sure to use `db` as the database name

Comment: close enough.. db should be used in place of host ip in wp-config.php and the link to db should be moved from nginx to the phpfpm part of the docker-compose

Comment: Links are not needed anymore. You remove that from your docker-compose